# EclipseLink JPA - Named Query - search on partial key in Composite key

Tags: jpa, ejb, eclipselink

The following is my JPA Entity class which extends Base class for Primary key which is composite.

Base Class

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TblParametersPK implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "idx1")
private int idx1;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "idx2")
private int idx2;

}
```

Entity Class

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_parameters")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "TblParameters.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TblParameters t")
, @NamedQuery(name = "TblParameters.findByIdx1", query = "SELECT t FROM TblParameters t WHERE t.pkId.idx1 = :idx1")
, @NamedQuery(name = "TblParameters.findByIdx1Idx2", query = "SELECT t FROM TblParameters t WHERE t.pkId.idx1 = :idx1 AND t.pkId.idx2 = :idx2))
public class TblParameters  extends BaseEmbeddedEntity<TblParametersPK> implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "paramvalue")
private String paramvalue;

}
```

When the Named Query TblParameters.findByIdx1 is executed which searches on one of the keys from the composite key, I see the following in the logs, it seems to add value and hash to the query if searching on only of the keys.

```
SELECT paramvalue, idx1, idx2, VALUE, HASH FROM tbl_parameters WHERE (idx1 = ?)
```

ERROR: column "value" does not exist

There is no issue when executing the named query TblParameters.findByIdx1Idx2 with both keys.

Since this is just a read only query, any ideas how to prevent the  VALUE and HASH injection in the query ?

The application is deployed on Wildly 20.0.1.Final and the DB is Postgres

Comment: This looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686637/hash-value-version-columns-generated-automatically-jpa which has the same problem of HASH and VALUE coming from somewhere. Just like it, you haven't given enough info on where these fields might be generated from - it isn't EclipseLink or JPA doing it. Look at what is generated for your entity classes to find out where the HASH and VALUE fields are coming from. If you do not want them persisted, they must be marked as transient. Alternatively, use ORM.xml and specify that only fields defined within it should be mapped

Comment: As a guess, try removing the @Data from the TblParametersPK to see if Lombok is adding these fields to help with the equals/hashcode method implementations. Something is somewhere in your entity graph.

Comment: I do not have these columns in the underlying tables not in JPA. Also, I tried removing the Lombok annotations and went with getter/setter methods. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: The Named queries with all keys in the composite work fine. The issue only happens when querying on partial keys.  When I moved the keys into the Entity class and added just an autogenerated ID in the base Enity with corresponding changes to the underlying table, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Table definition !=JPA. When ever you see an upper case column name defined in your selection clause, it is because JPA discovered a field/property in your class definition and used a default column mapping for it. So your entity classes have a property or field called Value or Hash with in it somewhere - it is up to you to find it. Alternatively, as mentioned, map your entity using ORM.xml instead of JPA annotations. This allows you to specify the ORM.xml file as complete and to ignore unmapped fields/properties it might discover in the class definition.

Comment: Your problem definition doesn't make sense - the issue should occur when ever you query for TblParameters. The select JPA uses must fetch the values from columns "paramvalue, idx1, idx2, VALUE, HASH" every time, and it will attempt to persist and manage those fields as well. This should have nothing to do with the partial keys used for search - but it might have to do with your embedded id, since that class definition means it is a part of your entity itself. Check out the lombok class definitions that get generated for this and the BaseEmbeddedEntity parent and anything else involved.